# json decode with an array in php

Tags: php, json

I am having a problem with getting data from json. I cant change the way it is saved in the database since it is generated by the framework and after that read for the fields generation. My json looks like this:

```
{"102":{"textinput":{"comment":"2"}},"104":"34"}

 OR

{"78":{"textinput":{"comment":"1"}},"82":"34"}
```

Comment value is my serialnumber that I net to get from this json. I tried with :

```
$json_sn = json_decode($customer_json_sn, true);
$snr = $json_sn['78']['textinput']['comment'];
```

But this is not the solution I need, since I never know the value of first numeric key, I cant rely on that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `array_keys` to get the keys and maybe `array_shift` on the result to get the first one?

Comment: are you just after the `comment` index?

Comment: you can simply use `foreach`. It would give the result.

Comment: yes, i need just the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this format is going to be always the same, you can use `reset()` function on this one. Consider this example:

```
$json_sn = json_decode($customer_json_sn, true);
$snr = reset($json_sn);
echo $snr['textinput']['comment'];
```

Comment: what in case when it is not the same?

Comment: @enigmaticus assuming the json structure stays the same, `reset()` will just take that first element, so you dont hav the need to manually put the key since it will always change.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$snr_array = array()
foreach ($json_sn as $key)
    snr_array[] = $key['textinput']['comment'];
```

Edit: I just realized that you might just need/get one comment:

```
$key = key($json_sn);
$snr = $json_sn[$key]['textinput']['comment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<?php

$json = '{"78":{"textinput":{"comment":"1"}},"82":"34"}';

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {

    # Check if exsit
    if (isset($value['textinput']['comment'])) {
        echo "Value: " . $value['textinput']['comment'];
    }
}
```